# z-index css related issue in Chrome Browser

Tags: jquery, css

I am creating  carousel/coverflow using JQuery and CSS in which we can see more than on number of slides on front.

In my code, I kept

- Front slides on z-index=1,
- left sides slides on z-index<0 rotated with y-axis with some angle
- left sides slides on z-index<0 rotated with y-axis with some angle
  In code 1st i am changing angle to 0 and then updating z-index;
  When I click on left slide to come on front this is working fine in Mozilla Firefox  & chrome,

for right side slide working fine for Mozilla Firefox but for chrome coming from 1st the right slide coming top of front slide then changing angle.

Issue is that if I am changing z-index later after rotation then why for chrome its coming top first then showing rotation.

And I am posting  question first time so *Sorry* if I am not able to explain the issue clearly.

Comment: here is some abut chrome ignorance and z-index. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365448/google-chrome-not-respecting-z-index

Comment: I shaw that previously also but  its not work I am using position: absolute only

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle or codepen to put your code in and for us to see what is happening really so that we can help.